# Weird behavior accessing tuple from Java

Tags: java, scala, tuples

I am looking for explanation and/or versioning details (if possible) about a very strange behavior I found in Java accessing tuples created in Scala.

I will show the weird behavior with an easy test I did.
I created this Scala class:

```
class Foo {
  def intsNullTuple = (null.asInstanceOf[Int], 2)
  def intAndStringNullTuple =  (null.asInstanceOf[Int], "2")
}
```

and then I run this Java program:

```
Tuple2<Object, Object> t = (new Foo()).intsNullTuple();
t._1(); // returns 0 !
t._1; // return null
Tuple2<Object, String> t2 = (new Foo()).intAndStringNullTuple();
t._1(); // returns null
t._1; // return null
```

does anybody have any explanation on the reason of this? Moreover, in my tests I am using Java 1.8 and Scala 2.11.8. Can anyone provide any suggestion about the compatibility of using `_1` from Java code also with older Scala 2.11 and 2.10 versions and Java 1.7? I read that `_1` is not accessible from Java, but I can access it in my tests. Thus I am looking for the versions which support it.

Thanks.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled, as I think ˋFuffaˋ should be ˋFooˋ, or vice versa, right?

Comment: yes, sorry! And thanks for pointing it out. Actually I created the example in my original language and in the translation of the name while copying and pasting I missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> does anybody have any explanation on the reason of this?

This is due to the fact that Scala has a specialization for the overload of `Tuple2<Int, Int>`, while `Tuple2<Int, String>` doesn't. You can see it from the signature of `Tuple2`:

```
case class Tuple2[@specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T1, @specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T2](_1: T1, _2: T2)
```

This means that the Scala compiler emits a class for the special case where `T1` and `T2` are one of the specialized tuple types, in our example there is a special class taking two ints, roughly like this:

```
class Tuple2Special(i: Int, j: Int)
```

We can see this when looking at the decompiled byte code:

```
Compiled from "Foo.scala"
public class com.testing.Foo {
  public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> intsNullTuple();
    Code:
       0: new           #12                 // class scala/Tuple2$mcII$sp
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokestatic  #18                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
       8: iconst_2
       9: invokespecial #22                 // Method scala/Tuple2$mcII$sp."<init>":(II)V
      12: areturn

  public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.String> intAndStringNullTuple();
    Code:
       0: new           #27                 // class scala/Tuple2
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: ldc           #29                 // String 2
       7: invokespecial #32                 // Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      10: areturn

  public com.testing.Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #35                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

In the case of `intsNullTuple`, you see that the `new` opcode calls `Tuple2$mcII$sp`, which is the specialized version. That is the reason your call to `_1()` yields `0`, because that's the default value for the value type `Int`, while `_1` isn't specialized and calls the overload returning an `Object`, not `Int`.

This can also be viewed by `scalac` when compiling with the `-Xprint:jvm` flag:

```
λ scalac -Xprint:jvm Foo.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                       jvm]] // Foo.scala
package com.testing {
  class Foo extends Object {
    def intsNullTuple(): Tuple2 = new Tuple2$mcII$sp(scala.Int.unbox(null), 2);
    def intAndStringNullTuple(): Tuple2 = new Tuple2(scala.Int.box(scala.Int.unbox(null)), "2");
    def <init>(): com.testing.Foo = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

---

Another interesting fact is that Scala 2.12 changed the behavior, and makes `intAndStringNullTuple` print `0` instead:

```
public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.String> intAndStringNullTuple();
  Code:
     0: new           #27                 // class scala/Tuple2
     3: dup
     4: aconst_null
     5: invokestatic  #18                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
     8: invokestatic  #31                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     11: ldc           #33                 // String 2
     13: invokespecial #36                 // Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
     16: areturn
```

Yields:

```
t1 method: 0
t1 field: null
t2 method: 0
t2 field: 0
```

Since now `null` gets transformed to `0` via `unboxToInt` and wrapped inside an `Integer` instance via `boxToInteger`.

#### Edit:

After talking to the relevant people at Lightbend, this happened due to the rework done in 2.12 for the bytecode generator (backend) (see https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176 for more).

Comment: thank you for your great answer and explanation! Do you have also some more details about in which versions I can use `_1` and  not only `_1()`? Or do you know where I can find this information? Thank you!

Comment: @mgaido Compiling this agains't 2.10, 2.11 and 2.12 seems to work.

Comment: thanks! I think that the java version is not relevant, isn't it?

Comment: @mgaido Java version does matter depending on your Scala version. For example, Scala 2.12 for the JVM currently compiles only to Java 8, as it has implementation specifics coupled to its compilation process (i.e SAM types). Specifically here the JVM version doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, need to call out, In **Scala**, everything is an **Object**, there is no [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)(for your code, it's `Int`) not like in **Java**, but **Scala** need to compile to **Java Bytecode** to run in **JVM**, since **Object** consume more memory than  **primitive type**, so **Scala** has [specialized](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/specialized.html) to solve this, it means generate the **primitive types** parameter method when annotated with `specialized` with types.

So for your code, it's [Tuple2](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L19), and it's **specialized** for `Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean`. this will generate the correspond **primitive type** constructor, like:

```
Tuple2(int _v1, int _v2) --> `Tuple2$mcII$sp`
Tuple2(long _v1, long _v2) 
...
```

And there is another thing need to clear, that's **Box** and **UnBox**, this means that compiler will decide whether the variable need to convert it to **primitive type** in compile time or convert variable to **Object**, find it more [BoxesRunTime](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/07d61ecf134dbba143531f5a1bd3c1289c437296/src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java#L15)

For the `intsNullTuple`, see bytecode :

```
 scala>:javap -c Foo
 public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> intsNullTuple();
    Code:
       0: new           #17                 // class scala/Tuple2$mcII$sp
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokestatic  #23                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
       8: iconst_2
       9: invokespecial #27                 // Method scala/Tuple2$mcII$sp."<init>":(II)V
      12: areturn
```

as you can see the above code, the compiler has decided to **unbox** Object to `int` by `BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt`, this is returning a primitive type `int. so it's actually will invoke`Tuple2$mcII$sp(int _1, int _2)`.

For `intAndStringNullTuple`, see bytecode:

```
  public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.String> intAndStringNullTuple();
    Code:
       0: new           #32                 // class scala/Tuple2
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokestatic  #23                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
       8: invokestatic  #36                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      11: ldc           #38                 // String 2
      13: invokespecial #41                 // Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      16: areturn
```

also you can see finally it has `boxToInteger` to a `Object`, its actually will invoke `Tuple2(Object _1, Object _2)`.

and for why `_1()` is returning `0` but `_1` is returning `null`, because **Java** generics only support `Object` type, `Tuple2<Object, Object>`, when you invoke `_1()` it's actual invoke `java.lang.Object _1()`, and it's equal to invoke `public int _1$mcI$sp();`:

```
scala> :javap -c scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp
Compiled from "Tuple2.scala"
public final class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp extends scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> implements scala.Product2$mcII$sp {
  public final int _1$mcI$sp;

  public final int _2$mcI$sp;

  public int _1$mcI$sp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #14                 // Field _1$mcI$sp:I
       4: ireturn
  ...
  public java.lang.Object _1();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #33                 // Method _1:()I
       4: invokestatic  #56                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       7: areturn
```

so `_1()` will return `0`.

for `_1` directly, it's actual access `Tuple2<Object, Object>` field, since it's `Object`, so it should be **null**.

```
scala> :javap -c scala.Tuple2
Compiled from "Tuple2.scala"
public class scala.Tuple2<T1, T2> implements scala.Product2<T1, T2>, scala.Serializable {
  public final T1 _1;

  public final T2 _2;
```

Finally, so for my understanding, since the **box** and **unbox** with **specialized**, we need to always try to invoke `_1()` not `_1`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in this case, I would need to use `_1`, because I need to know whether the value is `null` or `0`.  Do you have also some more details about in which versions I can use `_1` and not only `_1()`? Or do you know where I can find this information? Thanks.

Comment: if you just need to null or 0, I think you can just use `_1`, because `null` only occur when you set it's `null`