# Check if scala Tuple contains `null` in Java

Tags: java, scala, null, tuples

I have a Scala tuple which is:

```
val myTuple: (Int, Int) = (null.asInstanceOf[Int], 1)
```

and I am accessing from Java. The problem is that in Java, `myTuple._1()` returns `0` instead of `null`, as I was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606017/weird-behavior-accessing-tuple-from-java/47606319). `myTuple._1` instead returns always null, regardless of the value set. Thus I don't know how to check which is the real value: how can I check if it is `null`, `0` or any other value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in the Java world `null` is not a valid value of the `int` type. In the Scala world things are quite similar. If you just run

```
println(null.asInstanceOf[Int])
```

you'll get

> 0

as your output. This behavior is specified in the section [6.3 The Null Value](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html) of the Scala spec.

So you can't test for `null` in the `int` because it just can't be there. In the Java world the workaround for this is [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class which is immutable object wrapper over `int` and supports [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). So you may try to specify your tuple as

```
val myTuple: (Integer, Integer) = (null, 1)
```

However in the Scala-world there is a better replacement - `scala.Option`. And since Java 8 there is similar [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). So what you might really want is something like

```
val myScalaTuple: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (None, Some(1))
val myJavaTuple: (Optional[Int], Optional[Int]) = (Optional.empty[Int](), Optional.of(1))
```

Comment: thanks, I know which are the alternatives, but since this tuple may come as an input for me, I cannot change how it is. But unfortunately, you confirmed my feeling, ie. that there is not solution to this problem.

Comment: @mgaido, if this is an input, why do you want to check for `null` that can't be there anyway?

Comment: It can be, since the input comes from scala code written by the user and the user can write a tuple like the one I showed you.

Comment: @mgaido, you seem to not get the point. Even in Scala there can't really be `null` in the `Int` type. It is translated to `0` as my example shows. So even is Scala you can't distinguish between `(0,1)` and `(null.asInstanceOf[Int], 1)`. If you need a type that can hold whole `Int` range **_and_** `null`, you'll have to go for some alternative route.

Comment: It still can't be. Sure, the user can write `null.asInstanceOf[Int]`, but this evaluates to `0` the same as if they wrote `1-1`. You wouldn't ask how to check whether the tuple contains `0` or `1-1`, would you?

Comment: but if the user writes (null.asInstanceOf[Int], "2") the `null` is there, since there is no specialized class for this case. This looks to me like a bug.

Comment: @mgaido, this happens because in this case actual tuple type is `(java.lang.Integer, String)` and this is one of the alternatives I suggested. Yes, there is no way to create standard tuple `(Int, String)`, but of course you can roll out your custom class for such specific case that will have exactly this shape.